# Tropical trees and god-kings

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> To my north is the residence of an antique ruler.
>   To my east is a tower made of iron.
>   To my south is the tomb of a god-king.
>   To my west are tropical trees.

I have a big pool with music.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I bet you are at the

> Bellagio, Las Vegas which features an 8-acre lake by the strip.

To my north is the residence of an antique ruler.

> Caesar's Palace.

To my east is a tower made of iron.

> The Eiffel Tower, Paris Las Vegas hotel.

To my south is the tomb of a god-king.

> Luxor hotel, dedicated home of Amun Ra.

To my west are tropical trees.

> Palms Casino Resort.

Comment: Hehe, "I bet"... I see what you did there

Comment: Good game @Tom!

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> These sound like places in Middle America.

Reason:

West:

> Hawaii, an island full of tropical trees (and tourists)?

South:

> Mayan god-king tomb in Guatemala.

East:

> Sounds very like something made by the Aztecs, in Mexico and were able to make iron